# angular ui-grid rowHover Delete button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to solve this issue for a long time, but couldn't succeed so far.
I have a ui-grid and on row hover I would like to display a Delete button and on clicking the button the particular row should be deleted from the grid.

I followed these examples in stackoverflow or in Internet ingeneral, but none of them could solve the issue -

[Angular JS UI-Grid Delete Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122414/angular-js-ui-grid-delete-row)

http://jsfiddle.net/3ryLqa9e/4/

[Is there a way to display button in the angular ui-grid on mouseover on that particular row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626553/is-there-a-way-to-display-button-in-the-angular-ui-grid-on-mouseover-on-that-par)

Our ui-grid is dynamic where the column names are not known and are fetched by REST query.

I tried the following code -

```
 $scope.endPointsGrid = {
   //Other parameters ....
   //NO COLUMNDEFS since the columns are dynamic
   //This will just display the Delete button in each row, how to change it to row hover Delete button
   rowTemplate: '<button class="btn primary" ng-click="grid.appScope.deleteRow(row)">Delete</button>'
 }

 $scope.deleteRow = function(row) {
    var index = $scope.endPointsGrid.data.indexOf(row.entity);
    $scope.endPointsGrid.data.splice(index, 1);
 };
```

After pressing the button, I am getting the following error -

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
```

Can you please suggest me the correct way?

Thanks

Comment: We have a feature like that in our project, it's quite easy to implement what you want. But it is not enough details provided to say what's wrong with your code. Could you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: What is $scope.endPointsGrid.data ?